# needed index to make this sql query run faster

Tags: sql-server, indexing

here is the query I am stuck with:

```
SELECT *
FROM   customers
WHERE  salesmanid = @salesrep
        OR telephonenum IN (SELECT telephonenum
                            FROM   salesmancustomers
                            WHERE  salesmanname = @salesrepname)
ORDER  BY customernum
```

It is SLOW and crushing my CPU at 99%.  I know an index would help but not sure what kind or if it should be 2 indexes or 1 with both columns included.

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan?

Comment: Also, you might see if it gets faster if you do it as the UNION of two quieries rather than using an OR like that.

Comment: @Pointy  - SQL Server should be able to do an index intersection automatically if needed (once indexes actually exist!) @Slee - Can you just confirm whether you do actually pass both parameters? If you don't and you are just trying to do some sort of generic query that works for both then this will be a mistake.

Comment: @Martin yes you're probably right - however my time with SQL Server did make me pretty wary of "OR" :-)

Comment: Would it be reasonable to try LEFT JOIN instead of IN (subselect)? Did you try it, anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three indexes probably each on a single column. This is assuming that your queries are all quite selective relative to the size of the tables.

It would help if you told us what your table schemas are along with details of existing indexes (Your PKs will get a clustered index by default if you don't specify otherwise) and some details about size of tables / selectivity.

**Customers**

```
SalesmanId    
TelephoneNum
```

**SalesmanCustomers**

```
SalesmanName
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Query Execution Plan and see if there are any table scans going on. This will help you identify what indexes you need.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in addition to columns suggested by @Martin, an index on **CustomerNum** is also required since its used in order by clause.

If you have lots of records, the OrderBy is something which takes a lot of time. You can also try to run query without the orderby and see how much time it takes.